# startActivityForResult is undefined for class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog

Tags: android

I  am working in android. i want to make a custom dialog in which i want to add a paypal button.

this is the code for my program:-

```
public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
Button close;
String TAG="CustomizeDialog";

Context customize_dialog;

CheckoutButton launchSimplePayment;

public CustomizeDialog(Context context,String title_of_song,String artist_of_song,float price_of_song) {
    super(context);

    customize_dialog=context;

    setContentView(R.layout.paypal_custom_dialog);


    close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paypal_close);


    PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();

    if (pp == null) {

        try {


            pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(context, "", PayPal.ENV_NONE);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        pp.setShippingEnabled(false);
    }




launchSimplePayment = pp.getCheckoutButton(context,
            PayPal.BUTTON_118x24, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

    LinearLayout lnr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Paypal_Custom_Dialog_View);

    launchSimplePayment.setOnClickListener( this);

    lnr.addView(launchSimplePayment);




    close.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == close)

        dismiss();



    if(v==launchSimplePayment)
    {

        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();

        payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("2.25"));

        payment.setCurrencyType("USD");

        payment.setRecipient("kuntal_1316186174_biz@gmail.com");

        payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);

        Intent checkoutIntent =    
                 PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment,customize_dialog);

               startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1); **//this line is creating error that startActivityForResult() is undefined for type CustomizeDialog** 

    }



}
```

are we not apply CustomizeDialog() for a activity which is extending Dialog ? (as i done in my this program)
please suggest me what should i do for this ?
Thank you  in advance...

Comment: `startActivityForResult()` is available only in `Activity`, Get an instance of `Activity` inside `Dialog`

Comment: please suggest me sir how can i do this..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Activity whose theme is Dialog. This way you can achieve startActivityForResult as well as make it look like Dialog.

Comment: You can use full path "com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity" in the android:name while declaring in Android manifest file and try.

Comment: Hey Rahul bhaiya  i have done this by using the functionality of Activity having theme of Dialog. Thank you ji...

Answer (score 2):

this is my solution:-

1. i changed the extends Dialog to Activity.
2. I have changed the theme of activity in menifast file to dialog as follows:-
   `<activity android:name=".CustomizeDialog" android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />`
3. and this is the code which i have changed:-

--

```
package com.pericent.musicapp;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.Dialog;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.Window;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import android.widget.TextView;

import com.paypal.android.MEP.CheckoutButton;

import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPal;

import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity;

import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalPayment;

import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalAdvancedPayment;

import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalInvoiceData;

import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalInvoiceItem;

import com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalReceiverDetails;


public class CustomizeDialog extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button close;
    String TAG="CustomizeDialog";


 CheckoutButton launchSimplePayment;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.paypal_custom_dialog);


    Log.v(TAG, "i am gooing to perform close");

        close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paypal_close);

        text_view_price.setText("Price : "+50);

        PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
        if (pp == null) {
            try {

                pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "", PayPal.ENV_NONE);

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            pp.setShippingEnabled(false);
        }




        launchSimplePayment = pp.getCheckoutButton(this,

                PayPal.BUTTON_118x24, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

 LinearLayout lnr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Paypal_Custom_Dialog_View);

        launchSimplePayment.setOnClickListener( this);

        lnr.addView(launchSimplePayment);




        close.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v==launchSimplePayment)
        {




            PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();

            payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("2.25"));

            payment.setCurrencyType("USD");

            payment.setRecipient("kuntal_1316186174_biz@gmail.com");

            payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);

            Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment,this);
            startActivity(checkoutIntent);//startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);

        }



    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (resultCode) {

        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            break;

        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            break;

        case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:

        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


}
```